# Need help to accurately measure acrylic paint color into RGB

Tags: pantone, color-match

I collect anime cels and I want to measures all the color on the cels and store them as RGB data. I have tried scanning them with my calibrated Epson V600 scanner, the calibration was done using a 288-patches IT8 target with average deltaE of 0.6. However, that was still not enough to accuately reproduce the paint color.

I'm trying another way now by manually matching the color to the Pantone Color Bridge Guide and then search the Pantone library online for the RGB values. But the progress is going very slow because of that flimsy fan book and also because the guide doesn't have reference for all lighter color.

Is there a more consistent and reliable way to do this?

Comment: One question? What color peofile have you assigned for your rgb values so they match your pantone guide?

Comment: Have you already thought the next fact: The common RGB system (sRGB) cannot replicate all possible paint colors like they are seen in reasonable light. I guess your problem is elsewhere: Scanner's lamp maybe produces spectrally too sparse light which  humans can see as white, but the sparsely over the visible wavelength range distributed peaks cause in some color dyes totally different reflection than pure continuous spectrum white light. Epson V600 scanner uses led light. It can well have as sparse spectrum as fluorescent lamps. Epson promises nothing of the uniformity of the spectrum.

Comment: The entire point of being accurate is that how do you know what is accurate. Is your screen calibrated and or characterized.? Are you  viewing your pantone swatches and leaflet in a standardized light conditions? If not then its not terribly accurate. The only real way to do this is to take out a colorimeter or a spectrometer and measure the results in Lab or XYZ. Even so question is what to do with colors that you cannot do in RGB

Comment: (continued) make a test. Scan together in the same run a pantone sheet and a piece of anime material which looks the same for you in daylight. Do the scanner see them also equal? BTW. Do not believe screen colors if you do not have fully color managed computer- and software system and a properly calibrated monitor.

Comment: @joojaa My scanned images are in sRGB

Comment: @reddy yes but what RGB space does pantone specify? And what do they do to out of gamut colors? IN otherwords what is their  conversion intent.

Comment: @joojaa Pantone is also sRGB. When working on matching my cel to Pantone, I have pointed my iphone flashlight right on top until I find a color that match the paint.

Comment: @user287001 Okay, I'll test it tomorrow.

Comment: @reddy yes but that info is not enough theres 2 pieces of info you need to know is what target sRGB fíne, but you also need to know what the conversion intent is. Generally speaking there is 4 standard conversions. For accurate only absolute conversion makes sense. But what have they specified? See for general use absolute and pantone makes no sense because most colors would be out of gamut

Comment: about using iPhone: Looking the same in iPhone's light and seen through iPhone's camera tells nothing  of the sameness of the color when watched by a human in standard illumination. Our numerical color perception models except standard illumination. A proper color calibrator would be the thing to be believed if you want numbers.

Comment: Are you doing sort of a scientific analysis of the colors or is the end goal some sort of reproduction on paper? Just curious. Doing some art reproduction for CMYK print myself, so being "scientifically accurate" often isn't really especially helpful because of the obvious limitations of CMYK print. So it's often more about somehow getting a similar "vibe" to the print and accepting that it will never be a totally accurate reproduction. Have to "cheat" with very vibrant colors and make something slightly different which still sort of have the same overall look.

Comment: @Wolff I'm doing it for anime color correction, technology in this field has been matured enough to for example, if I feed an old anime that was plagued with color cast with the right color, I can restore its original color. But in order to do that, I would have to first build the color data of the paint. And they have to be accurate because anime are consist of big blocks of color, unlike real life footage that can get away with a miss here and there, a slightly off in hue in anime would turn a peach face into red.

Comment: Oh that's sounds fun! But haven't the colors deteriorated on the original cels you have? Don't know much about it but I would imagine the celluloid (or whatever it's made of) could turn yellowish over time.

Comment: @user287001 Hi I started looking for a matching Pantone color to a paint color for a comparison scan but most of the pairs I jotted down yesterday doesn't look the same anymore when I look at them now. And the few that actually still matches looks extremely similar to the color from my original calibrated scan when checked in photoshop...I'm beginning to have doubt myself now. Maybe my scanner do get the job done?

Answer (score 2):

Color is a bastard to get accurate. Note: here i assume accurate really means accurate and not something my eyes like discussion of anything else is pointless. There is several reasons for this even matching by eye to a Pantone guide may not really help you to be truly accurate results. Why is this?

A physical color reflected and when it reaches your eye is heavily affected by the color of the light you match under. Our eyes dont measure the actual physical action very well so the two things mix together. If you match under a incandescent light bulb, a led light and under overcast conditions and direct sunlight then you get different results. So a Pantone guide would only match accurately a Pantone color made with same print technology as the guide.

To combat this you have 2 ways:

1. You would need to much under a controlled light conditions then accept that there is some color deviation seen under some other light condition.

   Note you cannot use a camera for accurate because it does whitebalance and other things on top of the complicated problem.
2. You could measure the color with a colorimeter or a spectrophotometer. Later being better as the colorimeter really have problems of 1.

Now you say that I don't have a colorimeter, or spectrophotometer? Well that is usually not a problem you can probably find a source in your area that would be willing to lend or rent a tool for this use. Honestly suitable colorimeters aren't all that expensive these days.

Comment: Hi, the Pantone's color guide do come with a 5000K lighting indicator on the back of the fan book to test proper lighting. When I was using the iphone flashlight at night (because I don't have a lamp), the indicator did show a slight mismatch, but it was just slightly. I'll get a lamp asap to see how it goes. And regarding colorimeter/spectrophotometer devices, can you give me some reputable names to search for.

Comment: @reddy you should use the light in a room with neutral dim background so that your sample is brightest thing you see but not blinding.

Comment: Probably need one of these. Either 5k K or 6500 K https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=5000k+viewing+booth

Answer (score 1):

You need a spectrophotometer, for example a Spectro 1 Pro

EDIT: I suggest Nix Mini 3 (cheaper) instead of Spectro 1 Pro

Comment: Hi, I just tried out both the Spectro 1 and Spectro 1 Pro. The pro version is for measuring real paint so that we can look them up in the paint shop. The non pro version is for measuring the visual perceived color of the paint, which was my original intent. For the non pro version, it wasn't really that accurate, it did match for most darker color, but for the brighter one the device measured lower saturation and brightness. And for color like violet and pink, it simply gave out the wrong hue.

Comment: What do you mean with match darker color? Match with what? Pro version is to measure a visual match. Anyway after a while I moved to Nix Mini 3, much better than Spectro 1 for dark colors.

Comment: I measured the lab value of the paint and then paint them out in photoshop, then compared the displayed color to the actual cel. The darker measured color did match, while the brighter one doesn't. The pro version doesn't measure the visual perceived color but the actual value of the paint. For example, when measuring from the front(glossy side) of the cel, the pro version will measured the color without the gloss while the non pro version will measure the paint + the gloss.  If we measure a black paint, the pro version will give a Lab L* value of 22 while the non pro version will give a 6.

Comment: If you measure anything with the Spectro 1 Pro you can't easily reproduce it unless you add the glossiness again. Ex. you measure the phone, you get the LAB value, you order the paint and you paint a paper, color will be different because glossiness and other properties of the phone were not measured and reproduced.

Monitor comparison are even more difficult to do because you need a controlled environment (lux, ambient light, etc..), perfect calibration, etc... glossiness of the screen can't be changed too and so you need a very accurate position, etc..

Comment: Yes that's the point I'm trying to make about Spectro 1 Pro. Ideally the non pro version is the one that I should use, but like I said, it's wasn't really that accurate after my visual inspection. Now I'm going to try to do it with digital camera + color checker/camera target to capture the color this way. While waiting for the delivery of the equipments, I did do a quick test with iphone camera + x-rite color checker, the result color are all in the ball park but the 24 patches checker is definitely not enough, as there were like 10+ variation of skin tones in cel paint but only one orange

Comment: patch in the color checker. I'll see how it goes when my bigger color target arrives.

Comment: Spectro 1 is a toy, send it back and get a Spectro Mini 3 instead. Color checker is more tricky than what you may think because reference values are calculated under different conditions and patches are small and difficult to measure (with the Passport version). What do you want to achieve at the end of the story? Just measure a color or do you want to do some calibration?

Comment: Sorry, I read again your post. So first acquire data in the native scanner color space (= no transform) then do the calibration in the LAB space by using a software such as Light Resolve (MS Store) and then convert actual pages with that transformation by using the same software. Keep in mind that a delta of 0.6 is pretty good and probably within your calibration target tolerance. Why do you want more?

Comment: I returned my Spectro 1, it was a disappointment for that price. The problem with using scanner, which I recently found out, is that its LED light is too strong for lighter paint. Colors like red and pink will reflect very strongly to the hard light, making them super saturated when scanned, which is not the accurate representation of those color. So I'll have to soften the light or move the light source away from the paint before capturing the color, thus make sense to shoot them with a camera instead.

Comment: Yes, I'm not suggesting anymore Spectro 1 because for the price there are much better alternatives. Comparing Pantone RGB values is worthless because many colors are outside sRGB. Always compare LAB values.
1) Are you sure what's displayed by your monitor is accurate? Have you done the verification after the calibration?
2) How are you acquiring images from the scanner?
3) What's the IT8 target you used? Many are selling low-quality cheap target that are out of specs
4) I don't think you should get saturated luma with the bundled LED

Comment: Good luck in getting an uniform light with a Camera

Comment: My monitor and scanner are all calibrated. My scanner was calibrated using SIlverfast with the new 800 patches IT8 target. I think the reflection problem came from the fact that lighter colors paint were mostly semi-opague. I don't have this problem when using Spectro 1, where its light was very soft.

Comment: What's your monitor model? Calibration can't add colors that your monitor can't display. Scanner are usually designed to adjust the sensor gain so that there aren't overexposed parts. Can you share your raw scanned files and some Spectro 1 results?

Comment: Sensor in scanner has a wider gamut range than our monitors, in order to keep all the color as possible, I stored the scan with a ProPhoto RGB color profile. The image will then be converted into sRGB automatically when viewing them on the PC, where color that was out of gamut will be clipped (super saturated), they weren't overexposed. Here is a raw scan and a calibrated camera shot of this paint PB-3. As you can see, the paint was very close to the red on the color checker visually, but in the scan, it turned super saturated. The measurement from Spectro 1 is Lab (59, 64, 18).

Comment: Both the images are saved with ProPhoto RGB and 16 bit. [link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1UmY790kgvrUfKyR0g_zWuUbGkT98oRSb?usp=sharing)

Comment: The problem with your scanner image is that it is clipped in sRGB so can't be displayed correctly. Have you modified it with PS?

Comment: Can you share the same picture without any editing? I mean the file that come out from the scanner. I think you messed up something with the ProPhoto color conversion. Would be nice if you can share a raw scan of the Color Checker too.

Comment: raw = without touching it or changing the color profile to a different one from the default

Comment: There was no modification, the image was scanned in ProPhoto RGB color space for the maximum gamut possible. I only resized the image in photoshop because of the large resolution, everything was kept untouched. You only see it clipped on your side because it was converted to sRGB automatically by your pc. If you open it with photoshop that can work in ProPhoto RGB environment, you can check it out with the color picker window to see that the color was still inside the gamut of ProPhoto RGB. I included a scan of the paint chip along with the color checker in the link to show the difference.

Comment: There are few problems with your procedure. 1) You have the maximum gamut in the native color space 2) You need to convert to sRGB to correctly view things on your monitor 3) How do you convert from the Native Scanner Color Space to sRGB? You are going from the Native Scanner Color Space to ProPhoto, here first problem: the conversion assume that the source color space is sRGB

Comment: Read the previous comment and now have a look here:
https://we.tl/t-9jj8cyP0tZ

I had to lower the brightness a little to keep everything in the sRGB gamut, is the image on the right making more sense to you? I don't have the PB-3 paint to check, but the Color Checker looks very good after the Light Resolve calibration.

Please remember that if you want to compare anything on screen to real objects you have to calibrate to sRGB your monitor. Important: you need to calibrate for D65 at 80 cd/m2 that's a very dim monitor. You need an ambient D50 light too for the environment (5000k).

Comment: The whole point of that comparison scan is to show that the red paint reflect differently to the distance of the light source, that same paint was not oversaturated when I shot it with a digital camera is the proof. The paint color was captured incorrectly by the scanner from the start and there is no fix to it except ditching the use of scanner completely. The PB-3 from the calibrated camera shot is the correct color, I held the paint chip side by side to the image on the monitor and they did matched.

Comment: Look here the comparison

https://we.tl/t-zK1xLxgrBc

From the file you uploaded the PB-3 paint is having an RGB value of 211,86,84 so is not saturated in ProPhoto. After calibrating it with LightResolve you get an sRGB value of 186,32,57 that is not saturated too and can be very close to the right color.

Putting the paint chip side by side without a controlled illumination can bring to wrong conclusions. Other colors may also be wrong.

I don't recommend using a camera when a scanner is available, there is usually a way to fine tune the scan.

Comment: The sRGB value of the "scanner + LightResolve" color in your image doesn't match what you said. Its sRGB value is 241, 86, 98. And how did you calibrate it?

Comment: The paint color after the LightResolve correction is RGB 187,32,58 that is LAB 42,61,28. Now we have to adjust the L component (lightness) to 59 to match the lightness of the Spectro 1 measurement for the visual comparison (same story with the color from the camera). LAB 59,61,28 is RGB 241,86,98.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151954/discussion-between-reddy-and-gram).